# gnuradio installation in Ubuntu14.04.5

Tags: build, installation, ubuntu-14.04, gnuradio

I am trying to install GNURadio in Ubuntu 14.04.5 using the build-gnuradio script (https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGRFromSource#Using_the_build-gnuradio_script).

However, I have got all kinds of errors related to libzmq1.dev, latex, and function volk_32f_8u_polarbutterfly_32f(), etc. (even an error "unable to locate python-gnuradio package")

If somebody has successfully installed this software in Ubuntu 14.04.5 recently, can you provide the detailed steps for the installation here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Cindy! So, as someone who's been involved with GNU Radio a couple of years now: Please do not use Ubuntu 14.04 for new installations. It's not that it's impossible to make work, it's just unnecessary hard, and honestly, that is four years old, there's already a new long-term-support Ubuntu, and Ubuntu 14.04 is personally just something that I'd recommend to migrate away from. If you upgrade your Ubuntu to 18.04, you don't have to build GNU Radio yourself, but do an `apt install gnuradio` and get a good version;if you'd do the same on Ubuntu 14.04, you would get a totally obsolete GNU Radio.

Comment: (as a matter of fact: the full-support period of Ubuntu 14.04 has already ended, and even the "maintenance" update period ends soon. Ubuntu 14.04 is a system I'm not willing to take overly much care in supporting in the near future).

Comment: It looks like it is already installed. However, when I run gnuradio-companion, I got the following message: { Gtk-Message: 11:31:33.884: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" }. Any fix on this problem? How will this failure affect the usage of gnuradio?

Comment: Solution: uninstall, upgrade Ubuntu to 18.04, as I already said.

Comment: It is already Ubuntu18.04. I followed your advice here step by step. The installation process is very simple and easy, but there are still issues, such that module "canberra-gtk-module" can't be loaded, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been misunderstanding you here! So, does GNU Radio companion fail to start? (GNU Radio companion doesn't use sound at all, and canberra is a sound component for GTK)

Comment: Everything is OK except this problem and the other problem I reported in another post (Warning: failed to XInitThreads() — gnu radio running error --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319034/warning-failed-to-xinitthreads-gnu-radio-running-error). If I used the audio sink in my flowgraph, I will get an exit code (could -9). However, I can still hear the sound. Finally, other applications / flowgraphs that don't use a audio sink don't have such an exit code in the terminal when the executions end. I tried this several times.

Comment: Is there a fix to the above two issues ("canberra-gtk-module couldn't be loaded" and "failed to XInitThreads()") ?

Comment: I don't think the Canberra thing is anything that needs a fix! It is just a warning unrelated to GNU Radio